# How to display my prompt box input into my website page?

Tags: html, prompt, box

I want to have a html code where a prompt box pops up, the user has to enter the details and then the details will be displayed in my webpage all the time- even when the user refresh the page, the details will still be displayed in my webpage.

now i have the html code whereby a prompt box pops up, the user has to enter the details then the details will be displayed in my webpage. HOWEVER,the details will be cleared once the user refresh the webpage or go to another website.

so can anyone really help me? heres the html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>The human whose name is written in this note will die.</p>
<p>This note will not take effect unless the writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/ her name.</p>
<p>Therefore, people sharing the same name will not be affected.</p>
<p>If the cause of death is written within 40 seconds of writing the person's name, it will happen.</p>

<p></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Write Name.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter the name");
    var cause = prompt("Cause of death");    

    if (person != null) {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
         person + " will die of " + cause + " in 40 seconds...";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: save data in local storage

Comment: hi i am totally a noob when comes to coding. can you pls help me with the coding into my coding?

Comment: You want the data to stays even when the user clears cache/storage?
What language are you using in the backend?

Comment: this is how the code goes:

- in my webpage, there will be a button that stated "Write Name"
- user clicked on it and the prompt box pops up
- then user has to enter details like a name and click ok
- then another prompt box pops up asking for another detail like "cause of death" and user has to enter the details and click ok
- once user click "ok" the details will be displayed like "Name will die of heart attack in 40 seconds..."

so now what i want is that after the details has been displayed, i want the detail to be stored and displayed in the same page like "Name died of heart attack"

Comment: after the details "Name died of heart attack", the previous details that stated "Name will die of heart attack in 40 seconds.." can be cleared off.

the best thing is that you should view my website 
rpblackmarket.weebly.com
i need this for my school project